# Delphi XE5 64 bit DLL for Excel 2013 64 bit - Strange behaviour

Tags: excel, delphi, dll, 64-bit

I am trying to create a 64bit DLL in Delphi XE5 in order to communicate with the 64bit version of Excel 2013, yet without any success. Breaking down the problem to its simplest form, I wrote this simple code :

```
library test64;

function xx(x : double) : double; stdcall;
begin
    Result := x*2;
end;

exports
    xx;

end.
```

*I know that stdcall; is not needed, but kept it for compatibility with 32bit (it works perfectly in 32bit). Removing it doesn't change a thing, it is just ignored.*

and compiled it in Win64 platform. Declared this function in Excel 2013 x64 as follows :

```
Declare PtrSafe Function xx Lib "my path here\Win64\Debug\dll\test64.dll" (ByVal x As Double) As Double
```

Now if cell A2 = XX(A1) it always gives me zero. The floating value in A1 is always read as zero from the DLL side (I checked it in debug mode as well). However, the output from DLL to Excel works, i.e if it was :

```
Result := 100;
```

then A2 would read 100. I suppose that I am doing something terribly wrong but I cannot find out what it is. Any help please ? Thanks in advance.

*PS. 64bit version needs the full DLL path on the declare statement. 32bit does not (i.e. finds the DLL in the same path as the worksheet). Strange indeed...*

Comment: Addition : If I change x from double to integer (both in delphi and Excel), its value is always passed equal to 24 (ECX = 0x18), i.e. the result is always 48.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Note:*** The original version of the question included different code which omitted the `ByVal`.

The default parameter passing mode is `ByRef`. You didn't specify `ByVal` or `ByRef` and so the default is used. And `ByRef` is not correct. Your function does not match `ByRef`.

So you need to explicitly specify `ByVal`.

```
Declare PtrSafe Function xx Lib "..." (ByVal x As Double) As Double
```

I think that you get away with this in 32 bit mode because `Double` is larger than a register and so the parameter is passed by address. But under 64 bit the parameter is passed in a register.

The other problem is that you cannot call an external function directly from a worksheet. You need to wrap the call to the external function in a VBA function, and call that function from the worksheet.

```
Public Function Callxx(ByVal x As Variant) As Variant

    Callxx = xx(x)

End Function
```

Comment: Oops, just forgot to write it on my code (corrected now). However, nothing changes even if ByVal is included.

Comment: Can you post the code that you are using rather than fake code! Otherwise you waste everybody's time.

Comment: It's not a fake code ! It is exactly the code I am testing ! (my code = code on the example above)

Comment: The code without ByVal was fake. My answer looks moronic now doesn't it?

Comment: Anyway, I'll look at this later. Lunch now.

Comment: You mean that I shouldn't have corrected the code according to your answer ? However, the problem is still there.

Comment: I mean you should have posted the real code in the first place. Use the clipboard to do so.

Comment: I really did use the clipboard, honestly. When I wrote this simple example (which does not work) I just forgot to use ByVal, and I am sorry for that. I just wanted to post a simple example here, in order to focus on the problem itself without having to post my other more complicated code. Should I remove the question and repost it again ?

Comment: No it's fine. I have a solution now.

Comment: Thanks a million ! That worked fine, I suspect that this trick is needed only in 64 bit version right ? (the declaration is already placed in a standard module)

Comment: No sure about that. Don't have 32 bit Excel handy.

Comment: Thanks very much indeed ! Yes, the problem is totally solved.